# How can I make the speed of the puck slow down in an air hockey game?

Tags: c++

I'm making an air hockey game in c++ (this is my first program in c++). I have problems with the speed of the puck (it is slowing down, but never stops). How can I make it work? Here's the code wich controls the speed of the puck and the paddles (I have only 1 paddle yet).

(paddle1 contains the coordinates of paddle1, paddle1helper is the previous coordinate)

```
paddle1speed = Point(paddle1.x-paddle1helper.x,paddle1.y-paddle1helper.y);

if(puck.x > paddle1.x-40 && puck.x < paddle1.x+40 && puck.y < paddle1.y+40 && puck.y > paddle1.y-40) {
    if(paddle1speed.x <= 1 && paddle1speed.y <= 1)
        puckspeed*=-1;
    else puckspeed=paddle1speed;
}

puckspeed.x/=1,9;
puckspeed.y/=1,9;

puck+=puckspeed;
if((puck.y > winsize.y-15 || puck.y < 15))
    puckspeed.y *=-1;
if((puck.x > winsize.x-15 || puck.x < 15))
    puckspeed.x *=-1;

paddle1helper = paddle1;
```

I know it's not the best solution. Can you give me advices?

Comment: Are you sure it is slowing down? From your code, it only changes direction, or assumes `paddle1speed`.

Answer (score 1):

You are programming in the non-existent Continental C++ language, where floating-point constants have the form (for example) `1,9`. In Anglo-Saxon C++, the expression `1,9` is a comma-operator expression, which evaluates to its second argument: in this case, `9`. Try this instead:

```
puckspeed.x/=1.9;
puckspeed.y/=1.9;
```

Comment: Note that this is wrong concerning the comma operator. The expression `1,9` would evaluate to `9`, *not* `1`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is here:

```
puckspeed.x/=1,9;
```

You are using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), with operands `puckspeed.x/=1` and `9`, since the expression is parsed like this:

```
(puckspeed.x/=1) ,(9);
```

The comma operator evaluates the first operand, throws away the result, evaluates the second operand, and returns whatever that evaluates to. In your case, the net effect of the expression is

```
puckspeed.x/=1;
```

It is extremely likely that you meant to divide by `1.9`, which can be done like this:

```
puckspeed.x/=1.9;
              ^ HERE
```

GCC would give you a helpful warning, provided you compile with the `-Wall` flag:

> warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]

Comment: thanks :) actually I thought it was slowing down...
but I have other problems. The puck changes direction when it slows down (I think it's because the dividing).

Comment: @mitya221 no, I don't think it is because of dividing. You have some other bug somewhere else, or you don't understand another aspect of your own code.